# At what points does the function $f(z)=Arg(z)$ , $ z \in \mathbb Z-\{0\}$ have a limit?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

At what points does the function $f(z)=Arg(z)$, $z \in \mathbb Z-\{0\} $ have a limit ?

I know that $-\pi<Arg(z) \leq\pi$. Then how can I use that property to find points where limit exists ?

A where is $f(z)$ is continuous ?

Answer (score 2):

Except on negative x-axis,function is continuous everywhere.
Consider the point $(x,y)$ ,for $y>0$ ,$f$ becomes $arctan(y/x)+\pi$ so that the $\lim_{y\to 0^+}f(x+iy)=\pi$
Similarly ,approach the point $(x,0)$ from below x-axis.You'll see that both the limits are different.
PS: $x\lt0$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** 
Let

$z=x+iy$,
$$\arg(z)=\begin{cases}\arctan\frac{y}{x}&x>0, y\in\mathbb R\\
\frac{\pi}{2}& x=0,y>0\\ -\frac{\pi}{2}& x=0, y<0\\ \pi+\arctan\frac{y}{x}&x<0,y>0\\-\pi+\arctan\frac{y}{x}&x<0,y<0\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that,
$$
\mathrm{Arg}(z)=\mathrm{Im}\,\log z.
$$
The function $\log z$ is definable in every simply connected domain $\Omega$ which does not contain $z=0$. Hence, $\mathrm{Arg}(z)$ is continuous (and indeed real analytic) in every such $\Omega$.

Conversely, if $\mathrm{Arg}(z)$ is defined, as a continuous function, in a simply connected domain $\Omega$ which does not contain $z=0$, then $\log z$ defined as an analytic function.